# Java login with sqlite database

Tags: java, android-studio, authentication

Hi all please i need help because i have probleme logicale i dont know what is probleme in my code i create classe DB_SQLite and i wrirte this function

```
public Boolean loginValidation(String email, String password){
     Boolean ResFunct = false;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from login",null);
    res.moveToFirst();
    while(res.isAfterLast()== false){
        String idDb = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("ID"));
        String emailDb = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("email"));
        String passwordDb = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("password"));
        String nomDb = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("nom"));
        String prenomDb = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("prenom"));
        if(email == emailDb && password == passwordDb){
            ResFunct=true;
            break;
        }
        else{
            res.moveToNext();
        }

    }
    return  ResFunct;
}
```

and i create event onClick in button join

```
View.OnClickListener onjoin = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
         // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Join ...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String NomComplet;
            Boolean Valide = false;
            emailString = email.getText().toString();
            passwordString = password.getText().toString();

            Valide = db.loginValidation(emailString, passwordString);

            if (Valide == true){
                NomComplet = db.loginReturnNomComplet(emailString, passwordString);

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Join.class);
                intent.putExtra("NomComplet",NomComplet);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            if (Valide == false){
                AlertDialog.Builder a_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                a_builder.setMessage("Your information is incorect").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.cancel();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = a_builder.create();
                alert.setIcon(R.drawable.fff);
                alert.setTitle("Error");
                alert.show();
            }
        }
    };
    join.setOnClickListener(onjoin);
```

but the function return just false also when i enter valide email and password correct

Comment: Does your code enter the `while` statement?

Comment: yes the code enter while statement @yassadi

Comment: maybe the condition if statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For comparing two Strings, you need to use `.equals()` instead of `==` , otherwise they are not compared. So you need to rewrite your condition like this:

```
if(email.equals(emailDb) && password.equals(passwordDb))
```